# Marklogic Appbuilder widgets

Tags: widget, marklogic

I created an application using Marklogic Application Builder by clicking the New Application instead of New example Application.When I click the Assemble tab the Select Widget is disabled even though I could select the layout, but if I click the New example Application and click on Assemble all the widgets are enabled eg. pie charts, line chart etc. Can someone help me why is that when I click the New Application the widgets are disabled and thus I am unable to add widgets to my application. What am I missing , I was  not able to find in the documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The widgets rely on range indexes to provide the values. If your database doesn't have any defined, then you can't set up any widgets. The example application includes some range indexes configured on the database.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, you need to create a Search constraint that support faceting on the Search tab, and make sure the Faceted checkbox is checked. There are various types of Search constraints supported. The most commonly used type is the Range type, that is backed by a.o. element range indexes. You can also use Geospatial constraint, that requires presence of a Geospatial index in the database. You can also add a Collection constraint, that also supports faceting..